# Copy function not working

Tags: php

i am trying to copy a image from one folder to another folder but m getting now where with it

```
  if (!file_exists("user/$username"))          
    {
      mkdir("user/$username",0755); //making a directory

      $srcfile="/user/display_pic.jpg";
     $dstfile="/user/$username/display_pic.jpg";

      copy($srcfile, $dstfile); 
    }
```

so there is a picture located inside the folder named `user` and i am trying to copy that picture inside the folder `$username` (i.e the directory that is been created) the folder  `$username` is located inside `/user/$username' and the folder`user is located inside `/user/`

Comment: When working with files like this, you need to use **full paths** from your root, not relative folder paths.

Comment: you are not copying to the new folder. Look again. You copy to a file in the user folder, with name $username.jpg. Also, you mix relative paths and absolute paths. You should use absolute paths throughout.

Comment: i do not understand what you mean by the statement 'absolute paths' 
can you give me an  example

Comment: any errors outputted? Perhaps in the Apache log?

Comment: nope there was no errors

Comment: When working with the absolute paths do this $filedir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $whateveryouneed . "/data/uploads/"; obviously change for what you require

Comment: Of course you can use relative paths. You just need to ensure they are relative to the correct location. Use getcwd() to see where you are

Comment: This is the error i get `copy(/user/display_pic.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u313495632/public_html/test.php on line 15`

Comment: i was able to fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix this

```
$srcfile="user/display_pic.jpg";
$dstfile="user/$username/display_pic.jpg";
copy($srcfile, $dstfile);
```

my error was that i was using the `/` in the start